# Select row to be deleted in csv file in python

Tags: python, csv

This is maybe a very basic question, but let's suppose one has a csv file which looks as follows:

```
a,a,a,a
b,b,b,b
c,c,c,c
d,d,d,d
e,e,e,e
```

And I am interested in deleting row[1], and row[3] and rewrite a new file that does not contain such rows. What would be the best way to do this?. As the module `csv` is already loaded in my code, I'd like to know how to do it within such scheme. I'd be glad if somebody could help me with this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add columns to CSV while writing the CSV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20224912/add-columns-to-csv-while-writing-the-csv)

Comment: Instead of adding, you are removing, but the principle is the same.

Comment: Instead of `row += [...]` you'd do `del row[1]` and `del row[3]`. If in-place isn't needed, just open files normally and use the `csv` module.

Comment: Do you want to delete rows or columns? Because `row[1]` is a column in a row of data.

Comment: @martineau I wanted to delete rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since each row is on a separate line (assuming there are no newlines within the data items of the rows themselves), you can do this by simply copying the file line-by-line and skipping any you don't want kept. Since I'm unsure whether you number rows starting from zero or one, I've added a symbolic constant at the beginning to control it. You could, of course, hardcode it, as well as `ROWS_TO_DELETE`, directly into the code.

Regardless, this approach would be faster than using, for example, the `csv` module, because it avoids all the unnecessarily parsing and reformatting of the data being processed that the module has to do.

```
FIRST_ROW_NUM = 1  # or 0
ROWS_TO_DELETE = {1, 3}

with open('infile.csv', 'rt') as infile, open('outfile.csv', 'wt') as outfile:
    outfile.writelines(row for row_num, row in enumerate(infile, FIRST_ROW_NUM)
                        if row_num not in ROWS_TO_DELETE)
```

Resulting output file's contents:

```
b,b,b,b
d,d,d,d
e,e,e,e
```

Comment: This works correctly. Thank you very much for your answer. After thinking better about this, I agree that `csv` is not necessary for this task. As the `csv` I am manipulating were later loaded as an `np.array`, I found easier to delete the desired rows from the numpy array instead. However, I still believe this question/answer is good to keep for the record as it could be useful for others. Again, thank you for taking a bit of your time for answering this question.

Comment: muammar: Actually, since each row corresponds to a line in the file, this could easily have been done using only Python's built-in file I/O capabilities -- which wouldn't require any additional modules to be imported and would probably be faster as well. Now that I think of, that probably would have been an even better answer...