# Python CSV edit fields with numbers greater than a specific number

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have a csv file containing a distance matrix, and the part of it looks like,

[image]

There are many fields containing number greater than 1000000, and I want to write a python script to change numbers greater than 1000000 in the matrix to zero.

Here's my script, and I don't know how to **write zeros** in those field,

```
import csv

f = open('distMatrix.csv', 'rb')
csvreader = csv.reader(f)
element = list(csvreader)

i = 0
j = 0
while i <= 55:                            #this is a 56 * 56 matrix
    while j <= 55:
        while element[i][j] >= 1000000:
            element[i][j] = 0
        j = j + 1
    i = i + 1
```

Feel free to give suggestions, thanks.

I am using python 2.7.4 under Windows 8.1 x64.

---

**UPDATE#1**

I use the following code and get what I want (thanks, unutbu!),

```
import csv
import tempfile
import shutil
import os
os.chdir('C:\Users\Heinz\Desktop')

filename = 'distMatrix.csv'
with open(filename, 'rb') as f, tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='wb', delete=False) as g:
    writer = csv.writer(g, delimiter = ',')
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        row = [element if float(element) < 10**6 else 0 for element in row]
        writer.writerow(row)

shutil.move(g.name, filename)
```

the edited CSV looks like,

[image]

I just edited a little part of unutbu's script, and Martijn Pieters, thanks for giving me a resembling example.

Comment: Do you mean you want to write out a new CSV with those values changed?

Comment: I want to edit the CSV by changing those values.

Comment: See [Inline CSV File Editing with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16020858) for how to 'alter' a CSV file in-place or [Add columns to CSV while writing the CSV](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20224912) for a slightly more advanced option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import csv
import tempfile
import shutil

filename = 'distMatrix.csv'
with open(filename, 'rb') as f, tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='wb', delete=False) as g:
    writer = csv.writer(g)
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        row = [element if int(element) < 10**6 else 0 for element in row]
        writer.writerow(row)

shutil.move(g.name, filename)
```

Comment: The OP used `>= 1000000`, so you'd use `< 10**6`. Yes, that contradicts the actual narrative in the question.

Comment: Note that `os.rename()` will fail on Windows as the destination filename already exists; that's why [my version](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16020858) uses `shutil.move()` instead.